# Regular Expression won't match word when characters occur after a backslash.

Tags: .net, regex

I am trying to match domain user names of the format domain\t0xxx using regular expressions. I have gotten as far as getting it to match "domain\". Whenever I try to match anything beyond the backslash, the match fails.

For example:

```
string pattern = @"\bdomain\\\b"
```

will return true when compared like

```
   var s = @"domain\t0123";    
   var result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(s, pattern).Success;
```

yet when I add the t and try to match the same way, the result is false.

```
string pattern = @"\domain\\t\b";
```

Why is this happening? Is it now trying to escape the t? If so, how do I tell it not to do that? I have tried putting brackets [] around the // and the t, but that does not work.

Comment: Yes, it's considering `\t` as an escape sequence. You need to double the backslash to make it literal: `\\\t\b`.

Comment: imagine it's a typo in the question but you've left the first `b` out of `\domain\\t\b` which would make it try to match a number `\d` before `omain`.

Comment: @OGHaza: you save my life, I was so far away.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond guys! I gave Szymon's solution below a try and it worked. For the record, yes there was a typo in the question. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to just match strings like "domain\t0xxx", this will work for you if by xxx you mean digits. You just need to escape backslash by doubling it:

```
string pattern = @"domain\\t0\d{3}";
```

If the string should consist only of the above, you should use the beginning and end markers

```
string pattern = @"^domain\\t0\d{3}$";
```

Comment: That worked! I think I must have been over-complicating things. Thanks Szymon!

Answer (score 2):

In the regex you've shown I see 2 problems:

```
\domain\\t\b
 ^         ^
```

You've left out the `b` in `\b` so it's trying to match a `\d` (a digit) at the start.

The final `\b` also fails to match because there's no word boundary after the `t`. Add that back in once you've finished the regex and want to match the final position.

`\bdomain\\t` matches up to the `t` just fine.

Comment: OGHaza, can you explain what you mean about there being no word boundary after the t? Wouldn't "\b" be the boundary?

Comment: Hey Dave, I mean that a word boundary occurs between a word character `\w` and a non-word character `\W` (or the start or end of string). `t` and the `0` that follow it are both classed as word characters, so there is no word boundary after the `t`. The `\b` in your regex was trying to match a word boundary where there wasn't one.

Comment: But once again free code wins over answering someones actual question.